# How to get a settings storage path in a cross-platform way in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, cross-platform

My program needs to read/write a text (just a few lines) file with its settings to disk. To specify a path in code may work well on one platform, like windows, but if runs it on Linux, the path is not cross platform.

I am looking for a similar solution to `QSettings` that saves settings to different paths or has its native ways to handle this. Programmers don't need to do with the details. But the text file is not suitable to be saved as a value in `QSettings`.

No user interaction should be needed to obtain such path. The text file should persist across application restarts. It can't be a temporary file.

Is there an existing solution in Qt and what is the API that should be used?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The location of application-specific settings storage differs across platforms. Qt 5 provides a sensible solution via [`QStandardPaths`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstandardpaths.html).

Generally, you'd store per-user settings in `QStandardPaths::writableLocation(QStandardPaths::AppDataLocation)`. If you wish the settings not to persist in the user's roaming profile on Windows, you can use `QStandardPaths::AppLocalDataLocation`, it has the meaning of `AppDataLocation` on non-Windows platforms.

Before you can use the standard paths, you must set your application name via `QCoreApplication::setApplicationName`, and your organization's name using `setOrganizationName` or `setOrganizationDomain`. The path will depend on these, so make sure they are unique for you. If you ever change them, you'll lose access to old settings, so make sure you stick with name and domain that makes sense for you.

The path is not guaranteed to exist. If it doesn't, you must create it yourself, e.g. using `QDir::mkpath`.

```
int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
  QApplication app{argc, argv};
  app.setOrganizationDomain("stackoverflow.com");
  app.setApplicationName("Q32525196.A32535544");
  auto path = QStandardPaths::writableLocation(QStandardPaths::AppDataLocation);
  if (path.isEmpty()) qFatal("Cannot determine settings storage location");
  QDir d{path};
  if (d.mkpath(d.absolutePath()) && QDir::setCurrentPath(d.absolutePath())) {
    qDebug() << "settings in" << QDir::currentPath();
    QFile f{"settings.txt"};
    if (f.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Truncate))
      f.write("Hello, World");   
  }
}
```

Comment: This is old but in case someone else arrives here.. in QT 5.11 it appears to be QDir::setCurrent(const QString &path)

Comment: @Nick I have no idea what you’re trying to say. How does that relate to the question/answer? I’m not attempting to change the working directory anywhere, and that wasn’t the question.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to save some user related data, you can get user home directory path using `QDir::homePath()`.

Comment: It’s true that this would “work” in all cases. Yet it is very old-Unix-centric and leads to bad user experience. Even on macOS it’s bad manners, in spite of it being Unix. Some apps do indeed just punt it and write to `~/.appname`. But it’s not nice to anyone really. On Unix you should follow the FreeDesktop spec and write to `~/.config/app name[/...]`. Qt’s Standard Paths take care of it.

Answer (score -1):

There is [`QDir`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdir.html) to handle paths to dirs, [`QFileInfo`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.5/qfileinfo.html) for platform independent file information and `QDir`'s [`homePath()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdir.html#homePath)

My proposal is to use these classes and use `QDir::home()` or `QDir::homePath()` to find a directory where to write to, since the user has write permissions in his homedir and it exists on each platform.

Comment: `homePath` and then what? On Windows, that's in `%USERPROFILE%`, and if you start randomly scribbling there, you might be up for trouble. On OS X and Linux, that's in the home directory where you need to follow platform-specific path conventions. E.h. users who catch you writing to `.~/xyz` on OS X will dislike you. `QDir::homePath` is a legacy leftover and essentially useless for writing in a cross-platform setting. You can read from there, but not write without the user telling you where to write.

Answer (score -2):

You can store file in application directory. Take a look at [`QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#applicationDirPath).

From Qt documentation:

> Returns the directory that contains the application executable.

Comment: This is generally not writable, so it'd be a bad idea.