# Used current working directory by mistake... Where the heck is my database?

Tags: macos

I know that setting the database name for a SQLite database means setting the path to the DB file.
I set it like this:

```
db.setDatabaseName("DienstplanerDB.sqlite");
```

- this is wrong
- this is not how it's done
- but I did it

And somehow it worked but I could not find the created file via Finder or Spotlight.

**EDIT**

It was in the app package, see my answer below for information.
Also, see Kuba Ober's and Gombat's answers for useful advice.

Comment: In the 'current working directory' *when* the executable was launched?

Comment: @user2864740 this would be a directory accessible to spotlight and finder search wouldn't it? Otherwise, do you have an idea where the current working directory would be when using qt (it's not the build dir..)?

Comment: I suspect - although I have no experience in OS X! - that if it was launched from the finder itself the CWD might be the 'home directory' (eg. the result of `cd $` in a shell).

Comment: @user2864740 I just added OSX in tag and title, I forgot this. Well I search all those.. it's not there..

Comment: Could try a full-system `find` :}

Comment: @user2864740 was already in progress! It just spit out that the database apparently is inside the .app package. Which is really cool! Thx for your support :-)

Comment: Glad you found it. Consider posting the findings/result as an answer (which can be accepted).

Comment: See also [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32525196/1329652).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a `sudo find / -name "DienstplanerDB.sqlite"` spit out that the Database was created within the app package.

If you want to access it, right click on the "YourPorgram.app" and select *"Show package content"*.

The Database could be found at Contents/MacOS/yourDatabase.db

Answer (score 1):

It should be saved in the current directory. To obtain it, use [`QDir::currentDirectory()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.5/qdir.html#currentPath).

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with sqlite. Or even Qt. Or OS X.

The following project does the same on all platforms.

```
// main.cpp
#include <fstream>

int main() {
    std::ofstream{"DienstplanerDB.sqlite"} << "Ooops" << std::endl;
}
```

```
# project.pro (no Qt frameworks are linked to the executable)
CONFIG -= qt
CONFIG += c++11
TARGET = write-bundle-con-32533822
TEMPLATE = app
SOURCES += main.cpp
```

Now that you found it: you shouldn't have, because it's a wrong question to ask. Wherever it happens to be is out of your control. Why do you expect the initial working directory of your GUI process to be anything in particular? Don't. It's as simple as that. You have no control over it (zip, nada, zero, really). If you wish to locate things relative to the working directory, you must set it first yourself to point somewhere useful. Then there's no question as to where things are. Use `QStandardPaths` to get a platform-independent location for your database - `AppDataLocation` or `AppLocalDataLocation` would be a good choice. Make sure that you set your application name first via `QCoreApplication::setApplicationName`.

A properly developed application cannot assume that any initial working directory is writable (or even readable), nor that it has any particular value. Generally, on OS X the app bundle is not writable, just as the install folder isn't on Windows. Just because you can scribble all over it in a developer setting doesn't mean your users can, or that it is a wise thing to do.

Here's what your code just did to your user: They had a system from Yoyodyne, Inc.'s YodelAbteilung Deutschland. It had a `DienstplanerDB.sqlite` with €10k worth of data tucked in a safe spot. Did you seriously believe that you're the only person on the planet using sqlite, or dealing with rosters?! Since you write wherever you stand, you just overwrote it. You get sued for damages. Rightly so.

Don't wreck your users' data, please.

Comment: I really don't like your way of 'answering' this question that has already been answered. You can give advice, for which I am grateful. But please stay cool and don't throw random accusations at people. As stated in the question, I know that this was not even a path. I know that it was a mistake, but somehow it did work and I wanted to figure out why and where. Nobody ever asked for correctness. And since all of this happened working with qt on osx with a sqlite database, yes it all has something to do with it. I appreciate that you are trying to help. But this question is answered.

Comment: @BarthyB. First of all, there's no limit on the number of answers. Just because you got some answers doesn't prohibit others from providing more.  Then there's the issue of minimization - throwing stuff out of the question until nothing irrelevant is left. You'd have gotten the same result if you had a single-line main, no Qt or sqlite anywhere other than qmake-generated makefile that creates an app bundle. The minimization is an important part of any debugging process. It is one of the major ways of pinpointing what's wrong. Non-minimized questions create unnecessary noise in unrelated tags.